# Ros 2 Humble Hawksbill Installation on Windows

Tags: ros2, colcon, ros-humble, windows, overlay

I followed the official instructions for installing ROS 2 on Windows 11 Pro and the underlay works completely fine. But when I tried to create my own package and then tried to build using `colcon build --symlink-install --merge-install` the terminal throws an error. I don't know why. I tried restarting, repeating the commands but it still shows the same error. If anyone has any idea how to solve this, please fix this issue and provide the solution. Below is the error message for more clarity on what I am trying to say.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
It is better to paste the text from the error rather than a screenshot. Images are not text-searchable. Thank you for your kind cooperation.